# How to get Icon size to completely fill PushButton/be rescalable in PyQt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a class called TwoStateButton which inherits QPushButton so that the icon can change when the button is being clicked on and so the icon gets resized in proportion to the button when the whole window gets resized.

When I run this code, the button takes up the whole window and the icon is about 10% of the button. I'm trying to get it so that the icon image takes up the entire pushbutton and that they both get resized by the same amount when the window is resized.

What modifications to my code should I do to achieve this?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TwoStateButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, on, hover, parent=None):
        super(TwoStateButton, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pad = 4  # padding between the icon and the button frame
        self.minSize = 8  # minimum size of the icon

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(on))
        self.on = on
        self.hover = hover

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(TwoStateButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.hover))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(TwoStateButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("%s" % (self.on)))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        r = opt.rect
        h = r.height()
        w = r.width()
        iconSize = max(min(h, w) - 2 * self.pad, self.minSize)
        opt.iconSize = QtCore.QSize(iconSize, iconSize)
        self.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt, qp,self)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1090, 681)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.pushButton_2 = TwoStateButton(
            "images/Button5-3.png", "images/Button5-4.png", self.centralwidget
        )
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 310, 141, 81))
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setCheckable(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1090, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet(
            "border-image: url(:/images/Button5-3.png)"
        )
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wherever you resize your widgets, you want to have a line like `push_button.setIconSize(1 * QSize(push_button.width(), push_button.height())`. Note how you can add a factor in from of `QSize` to better match the provided icon's size and the widget.